# Why did the form Baron OF Somewhere drop out of use?

Tags: law, britain, nobility

### The Question

In the various **British** peerages - i.e. the peerages of England, Scotland, Ireland, Great Britain and the United Kingdom - one finds titles of the form *Duke of X*, *Marquess of X* and *Earl of X*. There are, of course, a great many baron-tier titles, but these are almost always of the form *Baron X*, *Baron Y* or *Baron X of Y*, and not *Baron of Y*. Why is this?

### Extra Details

- The only exception to the above that I've been able to unearth is the title of **Baron of Dunsany**. This exception seems to have occurred because said title is so very ancient. This makes me think that, in the earlier part of the Middle Ages, the form *Baron of X* was more common. Is that right?
- The title of **viscount** also tends to have been bestowed in the form *Viscount X* rather than *Viscount of X*. This makes some sense to me, since a viscount was intended to be, in the distant past, one of an earl's deputies, and so the title would naturally be more personal than territorial. Is this connected to the form baronial titles?
- Scottish **feudal barons** are always styled *Baron of X*. English feudal baronies were abolished by Charles II, and so records are patchier, but I can't imagine that English feudal barons were styled all that differently to their Scottish counterparts. The feudal baronage, both sides of the border, is an older institution than the peerage, hence my intuition the form *Baron of X* is older than *Baron X*.

Comment: Baron is the lowest order in British nobility. I'd be surprised if the form Baron *of* X was common at any point in time. Also, it's *Lord* X, rather than Baron X.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: In the most formal contexts it is ["*Baron of Dunsany*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_of_Dunsany#Style), that being the official formal title. However as these contexts are rare, "*Lord Dunsany*" is most often used.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy 'I'd be surprised if the form *Baron of X* was common at any point in time.' Well, at present that form is universal amongst the Scottish **feudal** baronage. You might well feel I'm moving the goal posts here! But the feudal baronage is older than the peerage, hence my feeling that the *of* form is older.

Comment: Sir John Sutton was made 1st Baron Dudley in 1528 under Henry VIII.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace But I did update the question! See the last bullet point thereof, which I added at the same time as replying to Denis de Bernady's cogent point.

Comment: I think this may be more of an English language question than a historical one.

Comment: Actually, 'Baron of x...' is not that uncommon. For example, [Baron Blunkett, of Brightside and Hillsborough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Blunkett), [Baron Clifford of Chudleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Clifford_of_Chudleigh), [Baron St John of Bletso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_St_John,_22nd_Baron_St_John_of_Bletso), and [Baron Grey of Codnor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Grey_of_Codnor).